# How to properly create a new file in Brackets

Tags: sass, adobe-brackets

I know this may sound easy but I can't really get my head around this.

I just begun using Brackets for primarily writing html, scss and css. I tried going to file > new to create a new file and start typing, it did create a new file and by default it was plain text.

When I tried to change the language from the menu at very bottom right hand side of Bracket's window, I found that this option was totally disabled.I tried to save the new file, it saved it but without any file extension at the end. when I tried the saved as it only gave me two options and none of the was the language extension I intend to save my file in(All files, Web files, text files). It just saved like this (Untitled-1) instead of (Untitled-1.scss).

So how to create files like normally I would do in any other IDEs?

Comment: Before save the file you can't change the language. When you save you have to write the extension manually

Comment: @blonfu So I create a new file and save it then close it, change the extension and re-open it and change the language to whatever I want to ?

Comment: You don't have to close. If you save the file you can change the language. If you write the extension Brackets recognize it automatically.

Comment: is there any other sophisticated way ? I mean that's not what I'm used to doing  in sublime text